# Super Simple Escape Sequence [Beginner]

Tags: java, escaping, sequence

I'm trying to replace "C:\FREQ\" with a whitespace.

```
String trimmed = files[i].toString().replace("C:\FREQ\", "");
```

But eclipse gives an error on the "C:\FREQ\" , saying Invalid escape sequence. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the backslashes:

```
String trimmed = files[i].toString().replace("C:\\FREQ\\", "");
```

Backslashes within Java text literals (String or char) are used for escape sequences such as `\t` (tab), `\n` (line feed) etc. To get an *actual* backslash, you need to just use `\\`.

See the [Java language specification section 3.10.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
String trimmed = files[i].toString().replace("C:\\FREQ\\", "");
```

The `\\` is readed like `\`